# Low volume via headphone jack in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers

I have a windows tablet that uses Intel drivers (generic?) for audio, and whilst the built in speakers' volume is fine, the volume outputted via the headphone jack is quite low. I have tried heard that disabling sound enhancements can help, but I have no such option.

The closest thing I have is something called "system effects" [image]
I have tried both disabling and enabling system effects to no avail.
I have also tried updating the drivers, but the newest versions are installed apparently.
In 'Levels' I have got the volume on full and the left and right channels on 100.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is what the volume mixer looks like:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of your Volume Mixer settings would be helpful

Comment: @Ramhound Done :)

Comment: What are your headphones? It does matter in case of high impedance ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your computer thinks you are currently "communicating" for some reasons:
[image: Sound Communications]

Try to select the "Do nothing" here. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately that hasn't fixed it..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles across this question:

Try installing the proper drivers for your sound card.

I was using the default audio drivers that Windows 10 automatically installed for a year without issues. Then when I reconnected my speakers one day, audio got really low. I switched to the headphone jack on the front and it worked fine for a while, until the same thing happened to it - audio got really low after I reconnected the speaker cable.

Then I installed the Realtek HD Universal Driver for my MSI MPG B550 motherboard and now the volume is normal again.